# Proof that there is at most one perfect matching in a tree

Tags: graph-theory, proof-writing

I'm trying to understand this proof to prove that there is at most one perfect matching in a tree.

> Let M, M' be perfect matchings in the tree T = (V, E) and consider the
> graph on V with edge set M ∪ M' .
>
> Since M and M' both cover all the
> vertices, every component of this new graph is either a single edge
> (common to both M and M' ) or a cycle. Since T is a tree, there can be
> no cycle, so we conclude that M = M'.

The only thing I have troubles to visualize is why if the component of the new graph is not a common edge then it should be a cycle.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are dealing with finite graphs. In this case, the following may help you understand the argument a little bit better although what I am about to write is not 'mathematically sound'.

Consider any component of the new graph and let $v_0$ be some vertex in that component. If that component consist only of a single edge, there is nothing left to prove as $M$ and $M'$ coincide on this component.

If, however, the component is more than a single edge, we do the following: By definition of $M$ and $M'$, $v_0$ is connected to some $v_1$ by an edge in $M$ (which is not in $M'$ since the component is not just a single edge). There exists exactly one edge in $M'$ (which in turn cannot be in $M$) connecting $v_1$ to some vertex $v_2$. We can do this little game to construct an infinitely long path using alternating edges from $M$ and $M'$. Since the graph is finite, an infinite path has to be a cycle.

If this is still unclear or you have any questions, leave a comment.

Comment: I still have troubles with this. To be honest I first read this first proof which I didn't really get, then I search the web to find this one and I'm still stuck. Maybe I'll try to understand what you've said...

Comment: @user2336315 Maybe I can make it clearer to you if you tell me what exactly you don't understand.

Comment: Given your proof or the one in my question, I have troubles to see how it should end in a cycle. In both proofs, it's "it has to be" or "then it should be". This is the only thing I really don't get, why it "should be". Maybe it's dumb but I'm stuck on that :)

Comment: @user2336315 Do you understand that one can produce an infinite path in the graph using my procedure?

Comment: Yes I think I get this part. It justs connect the vertices of the graph with both perfect matching assuming that it's not a common edge right?

Comment: @user2336315 Ok, now ask yourself this: How can there be an infinite path in a finite graph? An infinite path visits infinitely many vertices but the graph itself only contains finitely many. Hence, the infinite path has to visit some vertex at least twice (in fact, a lot more often but twice suffices :-) ). But if the path visits any vertex twice, it contains a cycle and that cannot be since your graph is a tree.

Comment: Thanks that is clearer now :-)